# При использовании fetch, не преобразовывается объект json в модель в контроллере. Почему так происходит?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет, я новичок в ASP.NET MVC, я пытаюсь послать данные на сервер, через метод javascript - fetch, а не через обычные asp-controller, asp-action, для того чтобы взаимодействовать с response от сервера, чтобы в зависимости от статуса ответа выводить разные всплывающие окна. Моя форма, с моим методом fetch выглядит следующим образом:

```
<form id="personalProfileFormId">
                        <input class="info-user-input" asp-for="Id" hidden="hidden"/>
                        <input class="info-user-input" asp-for="IsExamCompleted" hidden="hidden" />
                        <input class="info-user-input" asp-for="FinalGrade" hidden="hidden" />
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            Логин : <input class="info-user-input personal-profile-input-disabled" asp-for="Login" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            Имя: <input class="info-user-input" asp-for="Name" class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            Фамилия: <input class="info-user-input" asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between card-buttons-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id='updateInfoId'>Обновить информацию</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            Окончательный результат: @if (Model.IsExamCompleted == false)
                            {
                                <text>не получен</text>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    <text>@Model.FinalGrade баллов из 100</text>
                            }
                        </p>
                        <button type="button" align="center" class="btn btn-gradient text-white"
                                onclick="openModal({ url: '/PersonalProfile/GetLessonRecords',  modalId: 'modalWindow'})"
                                data-toggle="ajax-modal" data-target="Modal">
                            Список оценок
                        </button>
                        <br />
                        <p>Лекций пройдено: <input asp-for="LessonsCompleted" class="personal-profile-input-disabled info-user-input" disabled="disabled" /> </p>
                    </form>
```

Когда я отправляю данные через fetch, код javascript вот:

```
document.getElementById("personalProfileFormId").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

var updateFormInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('info-user-input');
var updateFormData = {};

for (let i = 0; i < updateFormInputs.length; i++) {
    let input = updateFormInputs[i];
    updateFormData[input.id] = input.value;
}
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(updateFormData);

const response = fetch('/PersonalProfile/UpdateInfo', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: jsonData
});
if (response.ok) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Информация',
        text: response.description,
        icon: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'Окей'
    })
}
else {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Информация',
        text: response.description,
        icon: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Окей'
    })
}
```

});

, в контроллере модель получает null, вот код контроллера:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateInfo([FromBody] ProfileViewModel model)
    {
        //return View();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var response = await _personalProfileService.UpdateInfo(model);
            if (response.StatusCode == Domain.Enum.StatusCode.OK)
            {
                return Json(new { description = response.Description });
            }
        }
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
```

Вот код модели:

```
public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите имя")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Длина имени должна быть больше двух символов")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Длина имени должна быть меньше 25 символов")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите фамилию")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Длина фамилии должна быть больше двух символов")]
    [MaxLength(25, ErrorMessage = "Длина фамилии должна быть меньше 25 символов")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public float FinalGrade { get; set; }

    public bool IsExamCompleted { get; set;}

    public int LessonsCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

Но. Когда я ставлю в параметр контроллера вместо ProfileViewModel тип object, то в object пишет что-то вроде такого: ValueKind = Object : "{"Id":"2","IsExamCompleted":"true","FinalGrade":"26,5","Login":"CommonUser02","Name":"maximka","Surname":"maximoff","LessonsCompleted":"5"}".

Моя суть вопроса заключается в следующем, как можно преобразовывать это сразу это в ProfileViewModel? Я видел что в других примерах оно преобразовывается. Что я делаю не так, и другой вопрос, возможно ли провзаимодействовать с response от формы без использования fetch, а используя стандартную форму на манер ASP.NET, c asp-controller и asp-action, и вывести всплывающие окна swal.fire, так как я это делаю с fetch в примере?

Comment: По поводу модели не знаю, но вот что вижу, так то что вы пытаетесь обратиться к `response.description`, но `response`, возвращаемый из `fetch` это не тело ответа, а сам ответ. Если вы хотите тело ответа прочитать как json, то нужно сначала сделать `const responseBody = await response.json();` и только потом обращаться к `responseBody.description`. Поправьте js код. Еще здесь ошибка `const response = fetch(`, надо так `const response = await fetch(`. В JavaScript `fetch` асинхронный и возвращает `Promise`, его надо вызывать либо через `await`, либо делать цепочку `then`.

Comment: Чтобы с моделью разобраться, попробуйте отправить asp-action и посмотрите чем запрос через форму отличается от запроса, который отправляет fetch. Вы уверены, что там json вообще должен быть? Может там url форма или multipart. Попробуйте `FormData` вместо json.

Comment: aepot, Вас понял, по поводу замечания js кода учту. Сейчас почекаю насчёт FormData. я правда не понял что такое  url форма и multipart:). я полный нуб пока в этом. Я бы использовал спокойно asp-action, но я не особо понимаю как взаимодействовать с response потом, в представлении, я же после отправки этого asp-action хочу окна выводить..

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:
JS:

```
    var response = fetch('/PersonalProfile/UpdateInfo', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: {
        "Params": jsonData
    }
});
```

C#:

```
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProfileViewModel>(Request.Body["Params"]);
```

Т.е. нужно в JS в body нужно не просто вставить свой JSON, а обозвать его как-то, например "Params". И в C# достать с помощью Request.Body["Params"]

Answer (score 0):

Выяснил что было не так, во первых надо было сделать async функцию и await fetch. И во вторых я считывал переменную "FinalGrade":"26,5" вот так, а должен был вот так: "FinalGrade":"26.5"
Я переписал javascript код следующим образом:

```js
document.getElementById("updateInfoId").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var updateFormData = {
        Id: parseInt(document.getElementById("Id").value),
        IsExamCompleted: Boolean(document.getElementById("IsExamCompleted").value),
        FinalGrade: parseFloat(document.getElementById("FinalGrade").value.replace(/,/g, '.')),
        Login: document.getElementById("Login").value,
        Name: document.getElementById("Name").value,
        Surname: document.getElementById("Surname").value,
        LessonsCompleted: parseInt(document.getElementById("LessonsCompleted").value)
    };

    const response = await fetch('/PersonalProfile/UpdateInfo', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(updateFormData)
    });

    const responseBody = await response.json();
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Информация',
        text: responseBody.description,
        icon: response.ok ? 'success' : 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'Окей'
    });
});
```

Comment: `description == ok` - что такое `ok`? Где оно определено? `if (response.ok)` можно делать, он true если статус-код от сервера 2xx. А потом в `Swal` вы опять пишете `response.description`, не исправили. Поправил вам остатки ошибок в коде.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!